# c# Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I've been struggling with this error for a while , can't understand why:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot' while attempting to activate 'Zipcode_Service.Models.ZipcodeContext'.

I tried looking at all the places the connection is being reconfigured , all seem fine :

ZipcodeContext:

```
public class ZipcodeContext
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public ZipcodeContext(
        IConfigurationRoot config,
        DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
}
```

ZipcodeRepository:

```cs
public class ZipcodeRepository : IZipcodeRepository
{
    private ZipcodeContext _context;

    public ZipcodeRepository(ZipcodeContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

ZipcodeController :

```cs
public class CityController : Controller
{
    private IZipcodeRepository _repository;

    public CityController(IZipcodeRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

My startup :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<ZipcodeContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IZipcodeRepository, ZipcodeRepository>();
}
```

Note: disabling the constructor of `CityController` and using an empty one works, I guess the error comes from the `_repository = repository`

Comment: it is because you are using `IConfigurationRoot ` in `ZipcodeContext`, I would rather recommend you use [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects) pattern.

Comment: Why does it matter ? In the tutorial I followed he used IConfigurationRoot and that thing worked. Why doesn't it works now ? @YuriyN.

Comment: Could you please link the tutorial? It doesn't work now, because in built-in Asp.Net Core dependency injection container, no service was registered to resolve `IConfigurationRoot` interface, when DI face it.

Comment: I can but it's in pluralsight so unless you have a user you won't be able to see it : https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=aspdotnetcore-efcore-bootstrap-angular-web-app&author=shawn-wildermuth&name=aspdotnetcore-efcore-bootstrap-angular-web-app-m0&clip=0&mode=live @YuriyN.

Comment: So how can I register a service to resolve `IConfigurationRoot` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways to deal with options in your case:

Simply register `IConfigurationRoot`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //...
   services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(c => Configuration);
   //...
}
```

Recommended way is to create special `ZipcodeOptions` class, and register it, using [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects) pattern:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //...
    services.Configure<ZipcodeOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ZipcodeOptions"));
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just call `services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(_config);` in `ConfigureServices`.