# Dependency Injecting IConfiguration within unit test class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 3, I have a helpers class that contains 2 dependencies, IConfiguration and ILogger, when unit testing the concrete implementation seen here:

```
public class Helper : IHelpers
{
    private IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<Helper> logger;
    public Helper(IConfiguration _config, ILogger<Helper> _logger)
    {
        configuration = _config;
        logger = _logger;
    }
    public Tuple<string, string> SpotifyClientInformation()
    {
        Tuple<string, string> tuple = null;
        try
        {
            if (configuration != null)
            {
                string clientID = configuration["SpotifySecrets:clientID"];
                //Todo move secretID to more secure location
                string secretID = configuration["SpotifySecrets:secretID"];
                tuple = new Tuple<string, string>(clientID, secretID);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogCritical("Configuration DI not set up correctly",ex);
        }

        return tuple;
    }
}
```

In my tests, I try to DI  helpers via this code:

```
public class HelperTests
{
    private ServiceCollection serviceCollection;
    private IHelpers helper;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IHelpers, Helper>();


        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        helper = serviceProvider.GetService<IHelpers>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetSpotifyConfiguration()
    {
        Tuple<string, string> devData = helper.SpotifyClientInformation();
        Assert.NotNull(devData.Item1);
        Assert.NotNull(devData.Item2);
    }
}
```

but I get the error that reads:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 
'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'Spotify_Angular.Helper'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.Net Core MVC Dependency Injection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801831/asp-net-core-mvc-dependency-injection-not-working)

Comment: @devNull unfortunately not https://stackoverflow.com/a/47279586/12526676

Comment: Where do you expect the value for e.g. `SpotifySecrets:clientID` to come from with this setup?

Comment: I think it's less about the `IConfiguration` vs `IConfigurationRoot` and instead about registering the configuration. But I suppose the answer in that question was more about the former. Here's one that is more related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46032491/5803406

Comment: appsettings.json @KirkLarkin

Comment: `IConfiguration` usually gets added to DI via a call to either `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` or `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`. That also sets it up to look at appsettings.json et al. For a unit test like this, I guess you'll have to build an implementation of `IConfiguration` and add it to DI manually.

Comment: Or use the Options pattern so you can just inject your own POCO and ignore `IConfiguration`

Comment: It looks like you'll have a similar problem for that `ILogger<Helper>` parameter, too.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an exception as you have not registered the configuration or logger interfaces with the DI container in your set up. You could do that, but may I suggest an alternative.

Rather than creating concrete implementations and registering them/creating a service provider, mock the dependencies. It'll make this process a lot easier and is more canonical in terms of how you should write your unit tests.

Include a reference to Moq then for the success case do something like:

```
[Test]
public void SpotifyClientInformation_ReturnsExpectedClientIdAndSecretIdTuple()
{
    var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<Helper>>();

    var expectedClientId = "My client Id";
    var expectedSecretId = "My secret Id";
    var configurationMock = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
    configurationMock.Setup(m => m["SpotifySecrets:clientID"]).Returns(expectedClientId);
    configurationMock.Setup(m => m["SpotifySecrets:secretID"]).Returns(expectedSecretId);
    var configuration = configurationMock.Object;

    var helper = new Helper(configuration, logger);

    var (actualClientId, actualSecretId) = helper.SpotifyClientInformation();

    Assert.Multiple(() =>
    {
        Assert.That(actualClientId, Is.EqualTo(expectedClientId));
        Assert.That(actualSecretId, Is.EqualTo(expectedSecretId));
    });
}
```

**Arrange** the dependencies and set up the test state; **Act** by invoking SpotifyClientInformation; and finally **Assert** that the resulting tuple has the expected values.

Following on from there you can easily increase your coverage for the null configuration case

```
[Test]
public void SpotifyClientInformation_WithNullConfiguration_ReturnsNull()
{
    var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<Helper>>();
    var helper = new Helper(null, logger);

    var actualResult = helper.SpotifyClientInformation();

    Assert.That(actualResult, Is.Null);
}
```

It is possible to assert the log message with another test but I don't believe it's realistic. All you're doing is reading values from the configuration instance and creating the tuple and I don't think either will produce an exception. Attempting to read a configuration key that doesn't exist returns null.

A better way **if you wanted to capture that scenario with a log message** would be to do it in the constructor

```
public class Helper : IHelpers
{
    private IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<Helper> logger;
    public Helper(IConfiguration _config, ILogger<Helper> _logger)
    {
        configuration = _config;
        logger = _logger;

        if (configuration == null)
        {
            logger.LogCritical("Configuration DI not set up correctly");
        }
    }
    public Tuple<string, string> SpotifyClientInformation()
    {
        if (configuration == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string clientID = configuration["SpotifySecrets:clientID"];
        //Todo move secretID to more secure location
        string secretID = configuration["SpotifySecrets:secretID"];
        return new Tuple<string, string>(clientID, secretID);
    }
}
```

Then if you want to assert the log message

```
[Test]
public void Initialize_NullConfiguration_GeneratesCriticalLog()
{
    var expectedLogMessage = "Configuration DI not set up correctly";

    var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<Helper>>();

    var helper = new Helper(null, logger);

    Mock.Get(logger).Verify(m => m.Log(
            LogLevel.Critical,
            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
            It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((o, t) => HasLogMessage(o, expectedLogMessage)),
            It.IsAny<KeyNotFoundException>(),
            (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>) It.IsAny<object>()),
        Times.Once
    );
}

private static bool HasLogMessage(object state, string expectedMessage)
{
    var loggedValues = (IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>) state;
    var unformattedMessage = loggedValues[^1].Value.ToString();
    return unformattedMessage.Equals(expectedMessage, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Personally I don't worry about null guarding DI staples like loggers and configuration. If I had to, I'd raise an ArgumentNullException to really ram it home that this class can't/shouldn't operate without it and I should fix the DI configuration before deploying. Doing that would mean you could do away with the null check in the `SpotifyClientInformation` method plus any null checking for blocks that consume `SpotifyClientInformation`.